# Is it a good practice in Javascript to use functions as C#-like properties to access private data?

Tags: javascript

For example, consider class Obj that has data variables a and b, and accessors for them, A() and B():

```
class Obj 
{
    constructor () 
    {
         this.a = 5
         this.b = 9 
    }

    A () { return a }
    SetA ( value ) { this.a = value }
    B () { return b }
}
```

The idea is to separate interface from implementation, to make code more flexible for future changes. So if you change something about variables a and b, you don't have to change all the code that uses them.

But i'm afraid it might create a lot of overhead because it wouldn't be optimized like in other languages. Also functions are first class citizens in Javascript so calling them is complicated.

Is it a good idea to access data like this? Or should this be avoided and how?

Comment: If you ever decide you need setters later, you can transparently transition to `set a(val) { ... }`…

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to access data like this?

I don't see any benefit, it just adds a lot of boilerplate.

If you need some kind of getter/setter later, you can transparently add it without breaking anything.

```
{ example: "test", }
// can be turned into
{ 
  get example() { /*..*/ },
  set example(v) { /*...*/ },
 }
```

As far as I can see the same applies to C#:

```
 string example
 // can be turned to
 string example {
   get {
     //...
   }
 }
```

so I'm not sure which "best practices" you are talking about.

> ... if you change something about variables a and b, you don't have to change all the code that uses them.

But ... if these properties change in a way  that it impacts their functionality, the code using it has to be changed too, using getters/setters to "make it still work somehow" is not a long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not write accessor methods in JavaScript. You don't need them now, you won't need them in the future. Keep your code simple.

```
class Obj {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 5
        this.b = 9 
    }
}
```

> make code more flexible for future changes.

JavaScript supports getter and setter properties. An accessor doesn't need to be a method, it works with normal property syntax (both accessing and assignment). If you later change your data properties to accessor properties, the code using them will not need to be adopted.

```
class Obj {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 5 
    }
    get b() {
        return this.a + 4;
    }
    set b(val) {
        this.a = val - 4;
    }
}
const inst = new Obj;
console.log(inst.a, inst.b);
inst.b = 46;
console.log(inst.a, inst.b);
```